# Deserialize the wrapper class

Tags: visualforce

How to deserialize the wrapper class in rest api and pass the value to vf page.I want to fetch the userlicense object and organization object information .After deserializing the value information should be displayed in vfpage

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class LicenseCount{



    public String getLicenseCount() {
        return null;
    }






    public String details{get; set;}

    public list<CompositeWrapper> lic{get;set;}

    public String options { get; set; }

     public List<SelectOption> getItems() {

        options.add(new selectOption('None', ' None '));

        options.add(new SelectOption('org1','org1'));

        return options;

    }
    public pageReference lic()

{
lic1();
return null;

}   

    public list<CompositeWrapper> lic1() { 


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();



        req.setEndpoint('callout:Namedcredentialname/services/data/v39.0/query/composite');
        req.setMethod('GET');

       req.setBody(
  JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> {
      'compositeRequest' =>
        new List<Object> {
          new Map<String, String> {
            'referenceId' => 'userLicenseQuery',
            'method' => 'GET',
            'url' => '/services/data/v43.0/query?q=SELECT+MasterLabel,TotalLicenses,UsedLicenses,Status+FROM+UserLicense'
          },
          new Map<String, String> {
            'referenceId' => 'organizationquery',
            'method' => 'GET',
            'url' => '/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+,name+FROM+organization'
          }
        }
      }
    )
  );

        //Get SessionId
        string autho = 'Bearer '+userInfo.getSessionId();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', autho);

        //Get Response
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPresponse res= http.send(req);
        string response = res.getBody();

        //Deserialize obtained json response




       list<CompositeWrapper> lic = (list<CompositeWrapper>)JSON.deserialize(response,list<CompositeWrapper>.class);
        return lic;
        }
        else{  //lic.clear();
        return null;
        }

        }


        public class compositeResponse{
  public List<CompositeWrapper> compositeResponse;
   public String id{get;set;} 
    public string name{get;set;} 
    public String MasterLabel {get;set;} // in json: type
        public String Status {get;set;} 
        public String TotalLicenses {get;set;} 
        public String UsedLicenses{get;set;}  

}
public class CompositeWrapper{
  public CompositeBody body;
  public Map<String, Object> httpHeaders;
  public Integer httpStatusCode;
  public String referenceId;
  public String MasterLabel {get;set;} // in json: type
        public String Status {get;set;} 
        public String TotalLicenses {get;set;} 
        public String UsedLicenses{get;set;} 

}
public class CompositeBody {
  public Integer totalSize;
  public Boolean done;
  public List<Map<String, Object>> records;


}
```

Vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="LicenseCount" >

     <apex:form >


     <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockSection >




        <apex:selectList value="{!details}" size="1">
   Organization:<apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}" />
  <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!lic}" reRender="abcd" />
  </apex:selectList>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>    

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lic}" var="key" id="abcd" >

            <apex:column >

            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!key.MasterLabel}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!key.Status}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!key.TotalLicenses}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!key.UsedLicenses}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!key.name}"/>



        </apex:pageBlockTable>

         </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>




</apex:page>
```

The above code is not fetching the information from user license and organization object.I am doing mistake in deserialization,please anyone guide me for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `CompositeWrapper` wrapper class is constructed incorrectly, and appears to conjoin data that's represented at multiple levels of the actual Composite REST API response. From the [REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/responses_composite.htm), the structure of that response is

```
{
   "compositeResponse" : [{
      Composite Subrequest Result      
      },{
      Composite Subrequest Result      
      },{
      Composite Subrequest Result      
   }]
}
```

Each subrequest result has the structure

```
{
  "body" : {       
      // Content here
  },
  "httpHeaders" : { 
    "Location" : "YOUR_URL_HERE"  
  },
  "httpStatusCode" : 201,
  "referenceId" : "YOUR_REFID_HERE"
}
```

Note however that the `body` key can contain a *different* set of content based on the inbound result. Since your two queries return different sObjects, the `body` elements are going to be heterogeneous and you won't be able to deserialize them into concrete sObject instances - the `CompositeBody` type is not constant across all of your requests.

The easiest way to approach this may simply be to use `deserializeUntyped()` to get back a `Map`-based structure that you can inspect, and optionally deserialize portions of in a strongly-typed manner. Alternately, you might make two separate callouts, possibly using a [Continuation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm#!) since you are in Visualforce context here.

I assume you're using this elaborate workaround because your code's running user does not have "View Setup and Configuration" permission. Note that you should not be using both a Named Credential and an Authorization header at the same time. Named Credentials are intended to manage authentication for you. Supplying the running user's Session Id will not achieve the privilege escalation you want.

Comment: can you construct wrapper class,for my code

Comment: I don't think it's even possible to do so in the way you want, although I'm open to being corrected by other users who spend more time working with JSON.

Comment: it is not possible right

Comment: Yes, as I said above. I'm suggesting that you use `deserializeUntyped()` instead, or simply make two separate query callouts, or use a Continuation.

Comment: can you help me correct my code uisng continuation and desrializeduntyped